Jest mockResolvedValue not working - function returns undefined in async context
I am trying to write a Jest unit test for an async function that loads and registers a list of commands. I am mocking the loadCommands function using mockResolvedValue but commandRegistry is always undefined in my main function.
For example:
main.ts - This module loads commands and registers each one.
import { loadCommands } from "./load-commands";

export async function registerCommands() {
  const commandRegistry = await loadCommands();
  if (!commandRegistry) throw new Error("commandRegistry is undefined");

  commandRegistry.forEach((command) => command.register());
}

registerCommands();

load-commands.ts - This module provides a list of command objects, each with a register method.
export async function loadCommands() {
  return [
    { 
      register: () => console.log("Registering Command 1"), 
      taskName: "Task 1" 
    },
    { 
      register: () => console.log("Registering Command 2"), 
      taskName: "Task 2" 
    }
  ];
}

Usage, if you run main.ts, it will log as expected:
Registering Command 1
Registering Command 2

Unit Test Problem
Here's the test I'm trying to write. I'm mocking loadCommands to return an array of mock command objects.
import { registerCommands } from "./main";
import { loadCommands } from "./load-commands";
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

// Mock loadCommands
jest.mock("./load-commands", () => ({
  loadCommands: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("registerCommands", () => {
  it("should load commands and call register on each", async () => {
    const mockCommand = { register: jest.fn(), taskName: "Mock Command" };
    (loadCommands as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue([mockCommand]);

    await registerCommands();

    expect(loadCommands).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockCommand.register).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

Run a test:
        throw new Error("commandRegistry is undefined");
              ^

Error: commandRegistry is undefined
              ^

Despite mocking loadCommands with mockResolvedValue, commandRegistry is always undefined in registerCommands. How can I ensure that registerCommands receives the mock data correctly?

The problem is that main.ts contains asynchronous side effects that occur on import. It's generally a mistake to have unchained promise, also this reduces the testability:
registerCommands();

That it throws an error results in unhandled rejection, which is not supposed to happen under normal circumstances.
function registerCommands and registerCommands() should be placed to different modules for the sake of testability, and the latter needs to be chained correctly like await registerCommands() with top-level await if it's supposed to halt the execution of the application.
